# 's3.Bucket' object has no attribute 'put': AttributeError

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3

I am trying to download a file from an URL and upload the file in an S3 bucket. 
My code is as follows-

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import print_function
import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree
from datetime import datetime as dt
import os
import urllib
import requests
import boto3
from botocore.client import Config

from urllib.parse import urlparse


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    """ Route the incoming request based on type (LaunchRequest, IntentRequest,
    etc.) The JSON body of the request is provided in the event parameter.
    """

    print('event.session.application.applicationId=' + event['session'
          ]['application']['applicationId'])

    # if (event['session']['application']['applicationId'] !=
    #         "amzn1.echo-sdk-ams.app.[unique-value-here]"):
    #     raise ValueError("Invalid Application ID")

    if event['session']['new']:
        on_session_started({'requestId': event['request']['requestId'
                           ]}, event['session'])

    if event['request']['type'] == 'LaunchRequest':
        return on_launch(event['request'], event['session'])
    elif event['request']['type'] == 'IntentRequest':
        return on_intent(event['request'], event['session'])
    elif event['request']['type'] == 'SessionEndedRequest':
        return on_session_ended(event['request'], event['session'])


def on_session_started(session_started_request, session):
    """ Called when the session starts """

    print('on_session_started requestId='
          + session_started_request['requestId'] + ', sessionId='
          + session['sessionId'])


def on_launch(launch_request, session):
    """ Called when the user launches the skill without specifying what they
    want
    """

    print('on_launch requestId=' + launch_request['requestId']
          + ', sessionId=' + session['sessionId'])

    # Dispatch to your skill's launch

    return get_welcome_response()


def on_intent(intent_request, session):
    """ Called when the user specifies an intent for this skill """

    print('on_intent requestId=' + intent_request['requestId']
          + ', sessionId=' + session['sessionId'])

    intent = intent_request['intent']
    intent_name = intent_request['intent']['name']

    # Dispatch to your skill's intent handlers

    if intent_name == 'DownloadFiles':
        return get_file(intent, session)
    elif intent_name == 'AMAZON.HelpIntent':
        return get_welcome_response()
    else:
        raise ValueError('Invalid intent')


def on_session_ended(session_ended_request, session):
    """ Called when the user ends the session.Is not called when the skill returns should_end_session=true """

    print('on_session_ended requestId='
          + session_ended_request['requestId'] + ', sessionId='
          + session['sessionId'])


    # add cleanup logic here

# --------------- Functions that control the skill's behavior ------------------

def get_welcome_response():
    """ If we wanted to initialize the session to have some attributes we could add those here """

    session_attributes = {}
    card_title = 'Welcome'
    speech_output = \
        "Welcome to file download Application. Please ask me to download files by saying, Ask downloader for download"

    # If the user either does not reply to the welcome message or says something
    # that is not understood, they will be prompted again with this text.

    reprompt_text = \
        "Please ask me to download files by saying, Ask downloader for download"
    should_end_session = False
    return build_response(session_attributes,
                          build_speechlet_response(card_title,
                          speech_output, reprompt_text,
                          should_end_session))


def get_file(intent, session):
    """ Grabs the files from the path that have to be downloaded """

    card_title = intent['name']
    session_attributes = {}
    should_end_session = True
    username = '*'
    password = '*'

    ACCESS_KEY_ID = '*'
    ACCESS_SECRET_KEY = '*+9'
    BUCKET_NAME = 'lambda-file-upload'

    url = 'https://drive.google.com/drive/xyz'
    filename = os.path.basename(urlparse(url).path)

    # urllib.urlretrieve(url, "code.zip")

    r = requests.get(url, auth=(username, password))

    if r.status_code == 200:
        with open("/tmp/" + filename, 'wb') as out:
            for bits in r.iter_content():
                out.write(bits)

    data = open("/tmp/" + filename, 'rb')
    # S3 Connect
    s3 = boto3.resource(
        's3',
        aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY_ID,
        aws_secret_access_key=ACCESS_SECRET_KEY,
        config=Config(signature_version='s3v4')
    )

    # Uploaded File
    s3.Bucket(BUCKET_NAME).put(Key= filename, Body=data, ACL='public-read')
    speech_output = "The file" + filename + "has been downloaded"
    reprompt_text = ""
    return build_response(session_attributes,
                          build_speechlet_response(card_title,
                          speech_output, reprompt_text,
                          should_end_session))


# --------------- Helpers that build all of the responses ----------------------

def build_speechlet_response(
    title,
    output,
    reprompt_text,
    should_end_session,
    ):
    return {
        'outputSpeech': {'type': 'PlainText', 'text': output},
        'card': {'type': 'Simple', 'title': 'SessionSpeechlet - ' \
                 + title, 'content': 'SessionSpeechlet - ' + output},
        'reprompt': {'outputSpeech': {'type': 'PlainText',
                     'text': reprompt_text}},
        'shouldEndSession': should_end_session,
        }


def build_response(session_attributes, speechlet_response):
    return {'version': '1.0', 'sessionAttributes': session_attributes,
            'response': speechlet_response}
```

I am getting the following error: -

```
's3.Bucket' object has no attribute 'put': AttributeError
```

I am trying to create an Alexa Skill which will download file from an URL. Hence I created a lambda function.I am new to AWS lambda and S3. I would really appreciate some help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As per the official docs [here](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.put_object_acl), instead of

```
s3.Bucket(BUCKET_NAME).put(Key= filename, Body=data, ACL='public-read')
```

you should use [put_object()](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.put_object) function as

```
s3.Bucket(BUCKET_NAME).put_object(Key= filename, Body=data, ACL='public-read')
```

Answer (score 0):

Bucket sub-resource of boto3 doesn't have an API method as **put**. That's why you are getting this error. The error is self-explanatory in that matter.

`'s3.Bucket' object has no attribute 'put'`.

Use the provided API method **put_object instead**. Or you can simply replace the line

`s3.Bucket(BUCKET_NAME).put(Key= filename, Body=data, ACL='public-read')`

with

`s3.Bucket(BUCKET_NAME).put_object(Key=filename, Body=data, ACL='public-read')`

---

For more information about the method syntax or parameters, visit [Boto3 Documentation of S3](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Bucket.put_object)

Answer (score 0):

Had similar issue due to different reason:

```
//This will give error while getting objects:
s3 = boto3.client('s3', region_name='us-east-1')
bucket = 'mybucketname'
//This works while getting objects:
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket = s3.Bucket('mybucketname')
//now get objects:
for object in bucket.objects.filter(Prefix="foldername/):
  key = object.key
```